# How to manage summer and winter datetimes in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a site where I need to store a lot of events with a start and end date. So I store the startDate and endDate at GMT time in the database.

However, when France switches to winter time, we end up with not GMT +2 but GMT +1. No problem for converting a DateTime to the correct time... But how do you manage dates that were set before the switch to winter time and are scheduled for the future (once winter time has been changed)? My whole schedule is off by an hour.

I think my problem is fairly trivial, but I'm having trouble understanding where I went wrong. What is the right way to do? How to avoid this type problem?

Thanks for your precious help!

Store datetime in GMT timezone in database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915498/how-to-deal-with-winter-and-summer-time#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=You%20could%20check%2C%20if%20there,(new%20DateInterval(%24interval))%3B

Comment: Store dates centrally in UTC, display/use them in the timezone of the local user when they are interacting with the data. Convert back to UTC again before saving to the database.

Comment: A schedule of future events should _NOT_ be stored as UTC (or GMT) in the database.  UTC is for _timestamps_ - that is, a precise instant in time that something happens (present/past). Ex: logging, order time, etc.  Scheduling _future_ times is more complicated, and values need to be stored in terms of local time at a specific time zone.  Converting to UTC is what leads to the very problem being described in this question.  See the linked duplicate answer for more details.